# How to install event filter on a custom Qt class?

Tags: qt, class, eventfilter

I want to install an event filter on an object of a custom class in Qt. So I created a project such as `QtGuiApplication1` on the Qt Designer and created a simple class as `myClass` as which has a widget and a QGraphicsView for drawing a colored rectangle.

in header file:

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_QtGuiApplication1.h"
#include "myClass.h"

class QtGuiApplication1 : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QtGuiApplication1(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
private:
    Ui::QtGuiApplication1Class ui;
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *ev);
    myClass* myClass_;
};
```

in .cpp

```
#include "QtGuiApplication1.h"


QtGuiApplication1::QtGuiApplication1(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    myClass_ = new myClass(this, QRect(100, 100, 200, 200));
    myClass_->installEventFilter(this);
}

bool QtGuiApplication1::eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * ev)
{

    if (obj == myClass_)
    {
        bool hi = true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and the myClass code is here:

header file of myClass:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QGraphicsView>

class myClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit myClass(QObject *parent = 0);
    myClass();
    myClass(QWidget* parent, QRect inRect);
private:
    QWidget * widget;
    QGraphicsView* qGraph_back;
    QGraphicsScene* scene_back;

};

#endif /
```

cpp file of myClass:

```
#include "myClass.h"

myClass::myClass(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

myClass::myClass()
{
}
myClass::myClass(QWidget* parent, QRect inRect)
{
    widget = new QWidget(parent);
    qGraph_back = new QGraphicsView(widget);
    scene_back = new QGraphicsScene(qGraph_back);

    widget->setGeometry(inRect);
    scene_back->setSceneRect(0,0,inRect.width(),inRect.height());
    qGraph_back->setBackgroundBrush(QColor(0, 0, 255, 80));
    qGraph_back->setScene(scene_back);
    qGraph_back->show();
}
```

I want to get all the events of `myClass_` object such as mouse event, But I can't and the eventfilter doesn't work. how to install eventfilter on the object?

Comment: Your eventFilter code looks correct. I just think the object doesn't receive any events, being a QObject and not a widget etc.

Comment: Do you mean event filter only works for widgets?

Comment: No, not as such, but there must be an event being sent to an object, and a plain QObject not hooked up with anything won't receive any.

Answer (score 3):

The event filter will work only for events in your `MyClass` instance, only. Not for its children.

So, events, such as a mouse click or move, in your `qGraph_back` will be not *visible* in your `eventFilter` method.

When you add a child in a widget, an `QChildEvent` event is raised. You can use it to install the *event filter* on all children (and grandchildren, etc.). But, you have to install the event filter on your `MyClass` before adding the children.

A quick example:

```
class Listener: public QObject
{
public:
        Listener(): QObject()
        {}

        bool eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event)
        {
            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << object << event;
            if (event->type() == QEvent::ChildAdded)
            {
                QChildEvent* ev = dynamic_cast<QChildEvent*>(event);
                ev->child()->installEventFilter(this);
            }
            return false;
        }
};

class Widget: public QWidget
{
    public:
Widget(QObject* parent) : QWidget()
{
    installEventFilter(parent);
    QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(this);
    auto layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    layout->addWidget(view);
    layout->addWidget(new QLabel("Foobar"))
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Listener* listener = new Listener();
    Widget* w = new Widget(listener);
    w->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

As you can see, the events in the `QLabel` are now sent to the listener. But, you can't see the events from the view because they are *caught* by the *viewport* widget in the `QGraphicsView`...

You have to handle the case where the added child has a viewport (inherits from `QAbstractItemView`, etc.) and it becomes more complicated.

So, if you have to know when the user clicks on your view, it would be easier to use signals/slots and not an event filter.

Comment: thank you for your time. do the `Listener* listener = new Listener();`  object must be created in main class?

Comment: You just need to pass it as parameter of `Widget` constructor. You can create it where you want.